# jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a function in my asp.net MVC view:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#dvGames').load(            
    '<%= Url.Action("Partial3", "LiveGame") %>',
    { gameDate: '2011-03-06' }      
);
    });
```

I want to pass date selected by user in jquery datepicker to gameDate. How can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to pass the date or the string representation of the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$('#dvGames').load(            
    '<%= Url.Action("Partial3", "LiveGame") %>',
    { gameDate: $('#id_of_your_field').datepicker('getDate') }
);
```

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, are you using the same id of the textbox to which the date picker was attached?

Comment: I have a input type= image with id= datePicker and I have a textbox named txtDate. user will click the datepicker and date is showin in txtDate. but on page load I want to set the txtDate with current date and use that date in $('#dvGames').load(

Answer (score 0):

You can specify as

gameDate: $("#gameDate").val()

Assuming gameDate is the id of the datepicker (textbox) control.

HTH

Regards,
Raja